# GNU Parallel threads running function without some of its given args

Tags: bcp, gnu-parallel

Running a set of GNU Parallel jobs across multiple nodes in a cluster and observing that all threads appear to be sleeping on the nodes (including the local node that called the command). Upon further inspection, found that GNU Parallel **appears to be removing some args when it runs the function assigned as a job**. Checking `parallel --version` does confirm that this is the GNU version of parallel (version 20160222).

The code in question looks like

```sh
bcpexport() {
    filename=$1
    TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN=$2
    DB=$3 
    TABLE=$4 
    USER=$5
    PASSWORD=$6
    RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE=$7 
    DELIMITER=$8

    <do some stuff to the given file arg $1 to BCP copy file contents to some MSSQL Server, function ends with...>
    
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "$TABLE" in "$filename" \
        $TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN \
        -U $USER -P $PASSWORD \
        -d $DB \
        $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE \
        -t "\t" \
        -e "$(dirname $filename)/bcperrors/$(basename $filename).bcperror.log"
}
export -f bcpexport
parallel -q -j $parallelization_pernode --sshloginfile $basedir/src/parallel-nodes.txt --env bcpexport \
    bcpexport {} "$TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN" $DB $TABLE $USER $PASSWORD $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE $DELIMITER \
    ::: $DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB
```

Which uses Microsoft BCP (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-2017) to copy TSV data into a MSSQL Server DB by distributing jobs across a set of nodes.

---

**Sleeping processes**:

When looking at the processes started on across the nodes via `clustershell` (https://clustershell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/clush.html)

```
clush -b -w mapr001,mapr005,mapr006 "ps -aux | grep bcp"
```

seeing a bunch of sleeping processes (notice the `S`, see https://askubuntu.com/a/360253/760862) as shown below (added newlines for readability)

> me     135296 14.5  0.0  77596  6940 ?        S    00:32   0:01
>
> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp TABLENAME in /path/to/tsv/1_16_0.tsv -D -S MyMSSQLServer -U myusername -P              -d myDB -c -t \t -e /path/to/logfile

Notice that the password arg `-P` is blank. This **does not happen when running the same function locally**. These threads appear to sleep forever (I assume MSSQL Server is waiting for a password, but since blank, none is ever given and so no response).

---

**Odd arguments**:

I also see some processes of the form

> me      11055 12.6  0.0 119640  1816 ?        S    00:46   0:08
>
> /bin/bash -c bcpexport() {  filename=$1;  TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN=$2;  DB=$3;  TABLE=$4;  USER=$5;  PASSWORD=$6;  RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE=$7;  DELIMITER=$8; some stuff from the function; /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "$TABLE" in "$filename" $TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN -U $USER -P $PASSWORD -d $DB $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE -t "\t" -e "$(dirname $filename)/bcperrors/$(basename $filename).bcperror.log" };
>
> export -f bcpexport >/dev/null;
>
> bcpexport /mapr/uceramapr.cluster.local//etl/ucera_internal/internal_etl/hph_clarity/version-2/stages/storage/CLARITY_TDL/tsv/1_27_0.tsv -D\ -S\ myODBCDSN myDB TABLENAME myuser mypassword -c \t

which appears to show (very new to using GNU Parallel) GNU Parallel taking the exported function from an assigned job and applying the arguments. However, you can see that the call to the function that parallel is assigning as a job shown at the end has the args `-D\ -S\ myODBCDSN` which was originally in the `$TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN` variable (which is why it was in quotes in the `parallel` call and why the `parallel` call uses the `-q` option). But now rather than passing as a single quoted are sting, it *appears* to be passing each piece of the string as if it were split up by the whitespaces (despite the `-q` option). IDK how this contributes to the overall problem (again, very new to Parallel), but it certainly does not look right.

This is all very weird to me any advice or debugging suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**: Further debugging into why these threads are sleeping suggests that they *may* in fact be doing their intended job (which would imply that the problem *may* be coming from BCP itself (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52748660/8236733)). From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47259/260742 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36200/260742)

> A process in S state is usually in a blocking system call, such as reading or writing to a file or the network, or waiting for another called program to finish.
>
> Your process will be in S state when it is doing reads and possibly writes that are blocking. Can also happen while waiting on semaphores or other synchronization primitives... This is all normal and expected, and not usually a problem... you don't want it to waste CPU while it's waiting for user input.

However, using the word "may" strongly here since this does not explain the missing $PASSWORD arg in the threads when checking `ps` or why the threads seem to never return. In any case, if the root cause turn out to be very different to my initial suspicions, will update the title and question to try to be more helpful to others who may have that same problem.

Comment: Add " around all variables. If the password contains special chars these could be expanded by the shell.

Comment: Add 'echo $PASSWORD' in the function to see if that is set correctly.

Comment: @OleTange At the top- / `parallel`-calling-script level, I do print the $PASSWORD variable and it is correct. Also had already added such an echo statement to the function *being called* by `parallel`, and commenting out the final BCP function call for the job and the $PASSWORD looks fine. This is why I suspect that `parallel` is applying the args to the function (given to `--env`) weirdly (especially since function works when using a while-loop locally instead of `parallel`).

Comment: Also the password only contains numbers and letters

Comment: There is too much of you code that does not work on my machine (e.g. I do not have `bcp`). Can you make an MCVE that would work on my machine and show the issue?

Comment: @OleTange Thanks for taking the time. Have been looking into this as well & may post a (partial) answer soon. One thing to note is that the threaded processes appear to *actually run* under certain conditions (eg. using `bcp` to export data a bit smaller than what prompted me to make this post) & when checking the process stats of those threads see that still no password (`-P`) arg is shown. Perhaps `bcp` just does not show this value to whatever `ps -aux` uses to get info (since does show the others) & not revealing the password out of all fields seems like could be more than coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. The sleeping processes**: I answer a very similar variation of this problem in another post (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787273/8236733). Basically, too many threads multiplied across so many nodes, seems to be overloading the MSSQL Server endpoint DB that the `bcp` operation is writing into (which I think is causing some kind of timeout issue from the remote DB).

As for the missing password (`-P`) arg value in the `ps` information (shown again here)

> me 135296 14.5 0.0 77596 6940 ? S 00:32 0:01
>
> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp TABLENAME in /path/to/tsv/1_16_0.tsv -D -S MyMSSQLServer -U myusername -P -d myDB -c -t \t -e /path/to/logfile

I suspect that `bcp` does something to hide that info from `ps` (so it appears just blank in the output (would have been more understandable if it appears as something like "xxxx" instead, but anyway...)). A discussion about other (conveniently for this theory, also Microsoft-made) programs doing just this kind of thing can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88665/260742

**2. The odd arguments**: In bash the `\` character basically says "use the literal value next character", from another SE post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146665/260742)

> shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a . ... The  ... shall be removed

So even though it appears that the single, quoted variable is getting split in the given output, it really is being entered as a single argument (the `\`s here indicating to the function to take the literal whitespace value and not take the separated strings here as different args). Eg.

```
[me@mserver001 tmp]$ ls "-l -h"
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
[me@server001 tmp]$ ls -l\ -h
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'ls --help' for more information. 
[me@server001 tmp]$ ls "-lh"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 10001 0 Oct 12 12:22 test0.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 10001 0 Oct 12 12:22 test1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 10001 0 Oct 12 12:22 test2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 10001 0 Oct 12 12:22 test3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 10001 0 Oct 12 12:22 test4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 10001 0 Oct 12 12:22 test5.txt
```

Notice that in the first two cases, `ls` is reading the whole argument and having a problem recognizing the blankspace `' '` in both the quoted example and the `\<blankspace>`-seperated example.

Perhaps I should change the title of the post to provide a better match in relation to the ending results of this problem.